# interconnected lists C#

Tags: c#, list

I have class with two properties which are Lists, one of it contents int - that's IDs of objects from second List. I override setters and getters to save them agreeable with each other. But when I add some this to list they are not synchronized. How to make them synchronized?

Here is code

```
public class Item
    {
    private List<Operation> _operations = new List<Operation>();
    private List<int> _operationsID = new List<int>();

    public List<Operation> operations
    {
        get { return this._operations; }
        set 
        {
            this._operations = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (Operation oper in value)
                {
                    this._operationsID.Add(oper.ID);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<int> operationsID
    {
        get { return this._operationsID; }
        set 
        {
            this._operationsID = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (int operID in value)
                {
                    this._operations.Add(new Operation(operID));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should I override List.Add if so, how it can me made?

Comment: You need to provide some sample inputs and what output you're getting and what "not synchronised" means. I mean one problem I can see is that in your setters you replace one list, but only add to the other one, so if you set one of the lists twice the other one will still contain elements from both sets.

Comment: It seems that you should use Dictionary<int,Operation>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what it is you are trying to do, but basically it seems like you need to encapsulate those lists so the user can't work on them directly (and get them out of sync). You do this by not exposing the lists to the user. Basically you are trying to keep the items contained to the user so whenever they work on your set of items, they would be forced to go through this class and the functions that class exposes. Your only issue then is to find out what to expose to the user and in what manner.

```
public class Item {
    private List<Operation> _operations = new List<Operation>();
    private List<int> _operationsID = new List<int>();

    public void addOperation(Operation o) {
        _operations.Add(o);
        _operationsID.Add(getIdentifier(o));
    }

    public void removeOperation(Operation o) {
        _operations.Remove(o);
        _operationsID.Remove(getIdentifier(o));
    }

    public void clear() {
        _operations.clear();
        _operationsID.clear();
    }

    public void findOperationMatching(Foobar foo) {
        //
    }

    private int getIdentifier(Operation id) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe such kind of approach will be optimal, instead of override List<T> or Dictionary<,>

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear previous list content before calling `Add` method:

```
public List<Operation> operations
{
    get { return this._operations; }
    set 
    {
        this._operations = value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            this._operationsID.Clear();
            foreach (Operation oper in value)
            {
                this._operationsID.Add(oper.ID);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this._operationsID = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But to be honest, I don't think it's a good idea to keep these things in two different lists. Why don't you use `Dictionary<int, Operation>`?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly it don't make any difference (at least in my programm). And suggestion about making dictionary is good, but I want to use all advances of seperate adding to each List with out know second value. In way of making it by dictionary -- another class should know my inside methods and it won't be any incapsulation.

Comment: OK, I think I know where is the problem. You're calling `Add` method on these lists, aren't you? Property setter is only used when you **assign** new List instance to the property, it's not called when you use `Add` method on existing property list.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After Add method of list it's logical become unsynchronized, and I want to find optimal solution to make it synchronized after each Add.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to try to manage two versions of the truth.  If it were me, I'd expose one `List<Operation>` that callers can Add/Remove, and a second `IEnumerable<int>` which simply exposes the ID's of the operations:

```
public List<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<int> OperationIDs
{
    get
    {
        return Operations.Select(op => op.OperationID);
    }
}
```

This way, callers can use the Operations list to do whatever they need to do (Add, Remove, Count, etc).  The OperationIDs is now not a second property that people can work with; instead it only reflects information that is in the Operations property.